# Regex for Facebook Photo ID from a URL in Java

Tags: java, regex, facebook

I’m trying to figure out a regex expression in Java to obtain the photo's id for this facebook url:

https://www.facebook.com/566162426788268/photos/a.566209603450217.1073741828.566162426788268/1214828765254961/?type=3&theater

I have come up with the solution

```
\w++(?=/\?)
```

but it does not work.

Help appreciated!

Comment: I forgot to add the part that the regex we want is the photo id

Comment: Then edit your question...

Comment: Searching for `facebook photo id` I doubt that you did a simple search on SO before posting your question. If you still hold on to your question and care to help others trying to give you an answer, please edit your question and say what specific sub string your trying to capture with the reg ex (e.g. `1214828765254961`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you could look for "\w+(?=\/\?)" and since there is no match groups extracted you get group 0.

Example snippet:

```
    String photoIdPatternAsString = "\\w+(?=\\/\\?)";

    Matcher postIdMatcher = Pattern.compile(photoIdPatternAsString).matcher(postUrl);

    if (postIdMatcher.find()) {
        postId = postIdMatcher.group(0);
    } else throw new IOException();
```

Comment: this is perfect